# ObjC no visible @interface for one instance but not another

Tags: objective-c

I’ve attached a screenshot of two lines that I believe are for, the intent of this question, the same. Both `inner` and `[MTInnerDisplay init]` are instances of `MTInnerDisplay`, yet when accessing the `subAtomForIndexType` on the `inner` instance gives an error.

I can compile and run accessing `subAtomForIndexType` with `[MTInnerDisplay init]`, but not `inner`.

In addition, if I factor out `[MTInnerDisplay]` into its own variable, and then reference it that way, I get the error as for `inner`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: 1. Please add the code as code, not screenshot. 2. Please add the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

[MTInnerDisplay init] is trying to call a class method named init. Highly unlikely that it exists.